# Assign a new public and static IP to a router behind my main router

Tags: ipv4, ipv6, tunnel, service-provider

[image: Diagram 2nd Public IP for 2nd Router]

What can you suggest to bring a second public and static IPv4 so I can configure my WAN-A interfase with my primary and an additional secondary IP settings so I can route all the traffic from the secondary IP to the second router (WAN-B), this way the segment 10.0.0.x/24 can receive and sent all the traffic from/trought the secondary IP.

**I want to clarify this is a production network operated by another engineer and myself, our company bring internet service as a WISP in our city, both of us have complete access to control, program and maintain it. (the showed diagram is not the real topology but for illustration purposes I simplify it in that way) **

In IPv6 I know that IPv6 Tunnel Brokers exists and works well but is there something for IPv4 ?

I appreciate your responses!!

Comment: can you explain little more. What do you mean by suggested service

Comment: @infra yes, I mean a service like https://tunnelbroker.net that allows you to have a public IPv6 using IPv4 service. In my case I would like to have a second IPv4 public and fixed address and send and receive all the traffic from the 2nd router trought this IPv4 address

Comment: Sorry, I am experience is not enough to provide answer for you.

Comment: Sorry, product or service recommendations or off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, you're looking for another /32 of publicly routable space. If so, you will need to contact your provider or even change providers as many residential providers may not be able to offer extra IP space.

Comment: Yes , you are right.. I call my provider and ask for an additional IP and they confirm they can assign one more IP for an extra fee. That was a surprise to me because when I started using their services, the installer told me they just can supply 1 IP